# Lightweight Rich Text Editor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for something very simlar to the SO WMD markdown editor that is extremely lightweight but I would like the text area to display the "preview" as you type. I have looked into many Rich editors but they are all seem to do everything under the sun. All I really want is Bold, Italic, Link, Image, and Lists (ordered/unordered).

Comment: Update: Phil Haacked has a cool jQuery plug in that does what i was looking for. http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/15/live-preview-jquery-plugin.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most lightweight way to go would be to roll your own. The simplest way to do it would be to use Javascript to react to changes to a `<textarea>`, and then update a `<div>` underneath it with the Markdown translated. A good Markdown implementation in Javascript is [Showdown](http://www.showdown.im/).

Comment: In my descrption i call out that i do not want a seperate div I it to function much like FCKeditor but with 80% less weight

Comment: My apologies, from the description it looked like you wanted something like Stack Overflow's, where the textarea shows the markdown and the div shows the preview. Here's a nice FCKeditor clone, which is supposedly lightweight: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/simple.php Not that I use it or anything.

Comment: Yea, i had seen that one through verious google searches, That is currently the main continder thanks!

Comment: @Fourth I updated the link. Some links on the page are still broken though, and a mirror is hosted [on GitHub](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown)

Answer (score 3):

I have just created this *Rich Text Editor* plugin that is focused to be used on public text editor such as comment form and/or Q/A form in a forum. It accept inline HTML only by default, but some hacks can be created to expand the limitation.

[image: Rich Text Editor]

https://github.com/taufik-nurrohman/rich-text-editor

#### Basic Usage

The CSS:

```
  <link href="rich-text-editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

The HTML:

```
  <textarea></textarea>
```

The JavaScript:

```
  <script src="rich-text-editor.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var editor new RTE(document.querySelector('textarea'));
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm a big fan of FCKeditor.

> This HTML text editor brings to the
>   web much of the power of desktop
>   editors like MS Word. It's lightweight
>   and doesn't require any kind of
>   installation on the client computer.

http://www.fckeditor.net/

Comment: FCKeditor does want i want but required a lot of config to get a simple UI. I want the look of SO WMD but features of FCKeditor

Comment: did you check out the toolbar options?  check this out.
http://www.fckeditor.net/demo/toolbar?toolbar=Basic

Comment: Yea i was hoping there was just something out there were i didn't have to do much work to configure it :) what can i say im a programmer im lazy :)