# Is there a lightweight jQuery text editor?

Tags: jquery, rich-text-editor

I have used jQuery's jqrte text editor, but it has many drawbacks.
Could anyone please suggest a lightweight jQuery text editor with common tools plus tables and an image upload link with browse button?

Comment: if you have a budget try redactor it costs money but way smaller than any real competitor (tinyMce and CKeditor) by like 80% http://imperavi.com/redactor/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a Rich Text Editor that is simple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674609/looking-for-a-rich-text-editor-that-is-simple)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/44072471/1163000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why dont you check

http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors