# Specify the way which the user can enter the data in text box

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, xhtml

Q:

I have a textbox in `multiline` mode and i wanna to force the user to enter his data as `points`.(Bullet-ed list) to be more organized . How to do this in a simple way.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" Width="300px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "multiline textbox", is that a textarea element or an input type text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution would be a custom control using ASP.NET and jQuery which automatically creates a bullet list and any time the user hits return a new row bullet will be added.

So you could guide the user in a more comfortable way.

Answer (score 1):

For this its better to make use of RichTextBox control rather than normal text control. because richtextbox control allows more flexiblity than the normal textbox.

get FreeTextBox from here : http://freetextbox.com/

serach on google : http://www.google.co.in/search?q=asp.net+%2B+freetextbox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: @just_name - check the google link pasted by me .. i think site is down but it will be avaialbe soon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902709/jquery-text-editor-lite-weight/2902877#2902877